# Why does the chat link on the right-hand sidebar only show up sometimes?

Tags: support, chat

I currently have https://rpg.stackexchange.com/ open in three different tabs.  In one of them, the right-hand sidebar has links to two rpg.se-relevant chat rooms:

[image: screenshot of rpg.se right-hand sidebar with chat links]

In the other two, there's just ads ([example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y85YP.png), [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcnyC.png))

---

How is this determined?  Is it randomized each time I load the page?  Is there a setting I can customize somewhere to change this behavior?

Comment: I've been wondering this too. I've been assuming it's just random.